# Is there a way to exclude cells that contain formulas from my Google Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, formula

Apologies is this has been asked already but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I've looked for several versions/solutions to this but can't seem to find one (I may be looking in the wrong place).

Basically, I'm looking for a way to exclude any cells that contain a formula from the following script. So I only want it to run this on cells that exactmatch "1". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2020");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace 1 with HOL
  replaceInSheet(values, "1", "HOL");

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Flow:

- getFormulas and replace only if the array of formulas is empty

#### Sample script:

```
function replace(sheetName = '2020', searchValue = '1', replaceValue = 'HOL') {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const values = range.getValues();
  range.setValues(
    formulas.map((row, i) =>
      row.map(
        (formula, j) =>
          formula || values[i][j].toString().replace(searchValue, replaceValue)
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: thanks for the response @TheMaster, forgive my ignorance, I'm new to coding. Tried CTRL+V ON this into the script but get Missing ) after formal parameters. (line 1, file "HOL").

Appreciate any help you could offer

Comment: @Aaron Read my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `getFormulas()` method to get all the formulas in the current shet and iterate through them like a 2d array.

```
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();  
  var formulas = sheet.getDataRange().getFormulas();  
  for (var r=0; r<values.length; r++) {
    for (var c=0; c<values[r].length; c++) {
      var cellValue = values[r][c];
      var formula = formulas[r][c];
      if (!formula && cellValue === "1") {
        sheet.getRange(r+1, c+1).setValue("HOL")
      }
    }
  }
```